# Convert type int64 to categorical using Python

Tags: python, pandas, types, dataframe

How I could convert this dataframe (all the columns) with type int64 to categorical?

```py
dfTrain.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25010 entries, 0 to 25009
Data columns (total 11 columns):
S1      25010 non-null int64
C1      25010 non-null int64
S2      25010 non-null int64
C2      25010 non-null int64
S3      25010 non-null int64
C3      25010 non-null int64
S4      25010 non-null int64
C4      25010 non-null int64
S5      25010 non-null int64
C5      25010 non-null int64
hand    25010 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(11)
```

Here is an overview of dataframe:

```py
dfTrain.head()
Out[145]:
S1  C1  S2  C2  S3  C3  S4  C4  S5  C5  hand    hand2
0   4   9   2   1   2   2   4   7   2   8   0   0
1   1   4   3   6   1   12  3   11  2   7   0   0
2   1   11  4   1   3   7   4   11  2   1   2   2
3   2   9   2   4   3   6   1   9   4   9   3   3
4   1   8   2   4   2   11  2   2   2   1   0   0
```

Comment: To convert after the fact, use ```astype()``` method, see documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/  But depending on how you got this data into a dataframe in the first place, you might be better off specifying the dtype at an earlier time (like when reading in a CSV, for example).

Comment: Thank you JohnE! Both posibilities works properly ;)